# Can a message be encrypted with BOTH mono-alpha and poly-alpha ciphers?

Tags: symmetric, classical-cipher, substitution-cipher, transposition-cipher

For my class assignment, I was given this text;

> Qpuvu vo vv stazpuykzh Hhycmlmv asb. Ad dhyaqva wh uyo uzb jpwww Avlw.
>   Tkpjllfdmbp zoatz vzjavfvna ZLHqh. Amva luy yyvlz yu bhk zua zlhvvalaz
>   yow llh uldu llzy yzlvao. Hzk caslyv kfzounf zayy sh pvsv. Uopz ala
>   yrvhbhm tk ppp Thlll jya. Blz o bblw tol Lsjay hba ljw oro lp nta
>   avlnktn.

There is more than one cipher method used, with one of their keys being 'ANNIE'

**POSSIBLE METHODS:** Caesar, Vigenère, One-Time Pad, Columnar Transposition, Railfence Transposition...

Using Cryptool 1 to analyze the histogram, I figured out that there's a Caesar shift 7 cipher, which decodes the text to:

> Jinon oh oo lmtsinrdsa Aarvfefo tlu. Tw wartjot pa nrh nsu cippp Toep.
>   Mdiceeywfui shtms osctoyogt SEAja. Tfot enr rroes rn uad snt seaootets
>   rhp eea newn eesr rseoth. Asd vtlero dyshngy strr la iolo. Nhis tet
>   rkoauaf md iii Maeee crt. Ues h uuep mhe Elctr aut ecp hkh ei gmt
>   toegdmg.

I figured out the plaintext by using columnar transposition through a website.

> jamesisanundercoverinterpolcophereportstoouroldenemysuptshamshuddinusingencryptedsmsestheyareawareofallouractivitesforthelastfourmonthsthepolicesuspectthatweknowtheyareworkingtogetjamesoutsetatrapforjamesandgetridofhimtonight

Is there a way I can explain why it couldn't have been Vigenère or a one-time pad? Is my assumption that a mono substitution cipher cannot be combined with a poly substitution cipher correct?

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that your Columnar Transposition Cipher (CTC) is as described as this [site](http://crypto.interactive-maths.com/columnar-transposition-cipher.html), since I found that the keyword `ANNIE` works.

### OTP

First of all, the combined cipher (Caesar shift 7 plus CTC) can always be the OTP, as long as we don't require a truly random OTP. The simple reason; x-or the plaintext and ciphertext get the OTP keystream.

This is your OTP key;

> zpgzmdgvimgddgwmfdypurgdaagcgqhhulnohospvisfikencaiuspaplrpvdszgpjctgigfzmlrtuordrxzuzttzyllcyuvcdmzbsvnorznadqieerdcneslflvnqztpknyohgagorodtazczrdypyshyrolzigrnvtxaceufmrjusmyvtichxpdxsttpsousllyccusveqhodrnpfzrzuubmtjyvqag

And if you asked if OTP can replace the CTC, the answer yes again with the key;

> sizsfwzobfzwwzpfywrinkzwttzvzjaaneghahlioblybdxgvtbnlitiekiowlszicvmzbzysfekmnhkwkqsnsmmsreevrnovwfsuloghksgtwjbxxkwvgxleyeogjsmidgrhaztzhkhwmtsvskwrirlarkhesbzkgomqtvxnyfkcnlfrombvaqiwqlmmilhnleervvnloxjahwkgiysksnnufmcrojtz

### Vigenère

In the Vigenère cipher, the password only affects $\operatorname{StrLen}(\text{password})$ characters whereas the CTC distributes the plaintexts implies they are not equal ciphers.

Note: If Vigenère is equal to CTC then the security will be the same as CTC.

**Note:** there may be a collision that is for some plaintexts a Vigenère Cipher will produce the same ciphertext as a CTC. This will have very low probability, and generating one is an interesting question.